# The analysis of 'for NP to VP' in HPSG

Tags: syntax, english, prepositions, conjunctions

This is from a paper titled "[What for?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330469157_What_for)" by Bas Aarts:

> (35) [<sub>NP</sub> It [<sub>S′</sub> [<sub>COMP</sub> for] [<sub>S</sub> Mary see his relatives]]] [<sub>M</sub> may] [<sub>VP</sub> distress John] 
> Bresnan’s account was very influential in proposing that COMP and S
> together form an S-bar constituent (indicated as S′ in (35)). However, it is not clear how *to* is accommodated in the clause labelled ‘S’. This analysis was adopted in later Government and Binding Theory in which ***for* was no longer regarded as being coupled with *to*, but as a single element**, although it was recognised that ‘[t]here are evidently relations between COMP and INFL (*that*-tense, *for*-*to*)’ (Chomsky 1981: 54). In more recent work this ‘**single complementiser analysis**’ has become the standard analysis in Chomskyan grammar, but also in other generative frameworks, such as HPSG (Head-driven Phrase Structure Grammar). For example, in **Sag (1997: 458ff.)** *for* is also treated as a complementiser – see (36).
> [image]
> Here *for* is regarded as an ‘object-raising element’. What this means is that the NP complement of *for* (*them*) is also the subject of the infinitival CP complement (*to go to the UK*), as indicated by the shared indices, and can hence be seen as having been raised out of the CP.

(Boldface mine.)

The author says that HPSG adopts what he calls ‘**single complementiser analysis**’, where *for* is not regarded as being coupled with *to*, but as a single element in the 'for NP to VP' construction. But [the cited HPSG work by Sag](https://scholar.archive.org/work/2ribfrylbvchhb6543sbeqall4/access/wayback/http://lingo.stanford.edu/sag/papers/rel-pap.pdf) treats both *for* and *to* as complementizers (C) in the 'for NP to VP' construction.

Does HPSG treat both *for* and *to* as complementizers in the 'for NP to VP' construction, as in the cited paper? If so, what does Aarts mean HPSG adopts what he calls ‘**single complementiser analysis**’?

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, the *for-to* complementiser is conceived of as a single complex complementiser. In Sag's (1997) analysis, *for* and *to* are separate complementisers. The *for* takes an NP and also a CP headed by *to* as a complement, where the NP is seen as having moved out of the lower CP.

Having said all of that, Sag subsequently ditched such analyses altogether. In his later work *to* is not a complementiser at all, but an auxiliary verb. See, for example, [Sag *et al* (2020) *Lessons from the English Auxiliary System*](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/EnglishAuxSystem.pdf).

---

<sup>**Reference:**</sup>
<sup>Sag, Ivan A.; Rui P. Chaves; Anne Abeillé; Bruno Estigarribia; Dan Flickinger; Paul Kay; Laura A. Michaelis; Stefan Müller; Geoffrey K. Pullum; Frank Van Eynde; and Thomas Wasow (2020): [Lessons from the English auxiliary system](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/%7Egpullum/EnglishAuxSystem.pdf). *Journal of Linguistics* **56**, 87–155. Published online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S002222671800052X.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. So did Aarts misquote Sag (1997)? Also, did Sag change his mind about [NP] and [_to_ VP] not being a constituent but being two separate complements of _for_?

Comment: I don't think so. The key bit there is *''for' was no longer regarded as being coupled with to, but as a single element*, I think. He's not overly clear, though, granted. Re Sag and *for*, I don't know, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the terms of GENERATIVE GRAMMAR including HPSG, but Sag 1997's (36) labels _to go to the UK_ as a CP, which means that _to_ is a complementizer (C). Then, is 'the key bit' in line with _to_ also being a complementizer? Also, is 'the key bit' also in line with CamGEL, which analyzes both _for_ and _to_ as subordinators (i.e., complementizers)?

Comment: @JK2 The key bit is that *for them to go* has just *for* as its C, not *for ... to*. The *to* is also a C, but it's not part of the head of the larger CP (it's not part of the *C* of the larger CP), it's just the C for a smaller CP constituent within the larger CP. Aarts's description is slightly confusing because he calls the analysis of the 'CP', the **single complementiser** analysis - where he means that the larger CP has only one word as its C. However, there are two Cs altogether because there's a smaller CP inside the bigger one. Main takeaway: there's no *for*-*to* complementiser.

Comment: @JK2 Re **Also, is 'the key bit' also in line with CamGEL, which analyzes both *for* and *to* as subordinators?** Well, yes and no. To the extent that subordinators are analysed as complementisers in GG, they're the same. But what you have in CamGEL is very different because subordinators are not heads. And in CamGEL a clause with a subordinator is a still a clause. And a VP with a subordinator (what?*!) is still a VP. In *for them to go*, there's only one clause in CamGEL. Btw, Sag liked to say that HPSG was a generative grammar occasionally, but I don't think others would think of it as one.

Comment: The first question, I got it. Thanks! // Re the second, isn't a complementizer in GG (and HPSG) also a marker of CP? Here's its definition in a linguistics dictionary: **complementizer (n.) (Comp, COMP, C)** In generative syntax, a term used to refer to subordinating conjunctions which mark an embedded sentence of a complement type, e.g. _that_ in _I said that he was leaving._

Comment: @JK2 Not in the way that a subordinator is a marker. In GG C is a head, not a dependent. With subordinating conjunctions, you add a subordinating conjunction to a clause and you get a clause. In GG you put a C and a clause together and you have a CP, not a clause. In CamGEL, a marker is a meaningless left edge signifier of clauses. Couldn't be less head-like if it tried. And in CamGEL put  a marker and a clause together, you get a clause.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One question. In Aarts's (54) (_That’s the best course **for you to take**_), _**for you to take**_ is an infinitival relative clause in CamGEL, whereas it's not a TP (clause) but a CP (complement of _best course_) in Sag (1997) and GG. Right? But Sag (1997) has **6.2 Simple Infinitival Relatives**, which starts with this sentence: "**Non-_wh_ infinitival relative clauses** like _to read_ and _for us to read_ [as in _One book (for us) to read was..._] belong to a distinct subtype of _non-wh-rel-cl_ that I will call _simp-inf-rel-cl_." What am I missing here?

Comment: @JK2 Yes, I agree that's confusing. Don't have time to comb through Sag's paper (1997 one) to see why all that might be the case. Specially as he completely ditched the *to* as C thing in the end! Just a note in passing: the CP does of course have a clause within it, and it's that clause that contains the gap. So it ***could*** just be a case of loose talk where he decides to go along with the conventional term on the basis of that, even though he's really talking about CP modifiers, not clausal ones. (shrugs)

Comment: I don't think it's loose talk, because _rel-cl_ means _rel(ative)-cl(ause)_ as shown on page 13.

Comment: @JK2 Yes, loose labelling is more the kind of thing I was angling at. No-one would recognise 'relative comp'.

Comment: After reviewing some GG meterials, I realized that a CP is always called a "clause" in Generative Grammar. So it may not be any "loose talk/labeling" on the part of Sag (1997) or HPSG. In fact, I've not found any GG or HPSG text that says that CP is not a clause because the head is C. In GG/HPSG, all X('head') says is that the **phrase** having X as the head is called XP. That is, the head of a **phrase** is the word that gives the **phrase** its category. The thing about GG/HPSG is, this concept of **phrase** is extended to CP and TP, both of which are clauses.

Comment: @JK2 The main reason that I sense a clause/CP difference in GG is not because there's a difference between a clause and a phrase, but because Greg Lee, the only GGn on EL&U used to have verbal fist fights with me every time I referred to a subordinate declarative clause as a clause. See all of Greg's comments here, for example (there's long gaps between some of them) **:** ["By the way, Araucaria's analysis of his example 10 is highly original. Yes, highly."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505596/how-the-west-was-won-is-this-a-noun-phrase/505651#comment1222866_505651)

Comment: It's not entirely clear from those comments whether Greg was saying what you think he said, and why he was saying it. What I've learned from reading some GG stuff is that CP is a clause in GG just as TP is.

Comment: @JK2 It's all a bit vague apart from this bit: **The subject of 10 is obviously not a finite clause**. I can't work out what else he could have meant there. However, no disagreement from me that GG's regard CPs as clauses. (I simply wouldn't know!. My knowledge of the ins an outs of GG re pretty superficial.) The only thing I find odd is that "clause" is a phrasal category label. Having two phrasal categories with different heads regarded as the same type of phrasal category feels weird to me. (shrugs)

Comment: CP and IP are "clausal categories" or "nonlexical categories" as opposed to NP and VP, which are "lexical categories". See the bottom two paragraphs (page 3) of Barriers (1986) by N Chomsky: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Barriers/-62A4RZhcrIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+clausal+categories+conventionally+labeled+S+and+S%27+might+be+I%22+and+C%22,+respectively%22&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover